# Will the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm always find the max flow if we start from a valid flow?

Tags: algorithms, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

I stumbled across this question and answer ([source](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/summer11/cps130/files/practice-final.pdf)):

> Question: Suppose someone presents you with a solution to a max-flow problem on some network. Give a linear
>   time algorithm to determine whether the solution does indeed give a maximum flow.
>
> Answer: First, verify that the solution is a valid flow by comparing the flow on each edge to the capacity of
>   each edge, for cost O(|E|). If the solution is a valid flow, then compose the residual graph (O(|E|))
>   and look for an augmenting path, which using BFS is O(|V | + |E|). The existence of an augmenting
>   path would mean the solution is not a maximum flow.

Does this mean that the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm will reach max flow if given **any** valid flow as input, instead of initializing all edges to 0 at the start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If the flow is not maximum, then there is an augmenting path. If there's an augmenting path, Ford-Fulkerson will find it (and continue to find them until the flow is maximum). Starting from a different initial flow does not change this.